# Como juntar mais de dois dataframes no R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Tenho uma lista de 12 `DF's` que necessito juntar em um único `DF`. A estrutura de todos é igual, só diferindo o nome da segunda coluna, desta forma, a estrutura básica é: Coluna 1 é a data e Coluna 2 o nome do objeto.

Os `DF's` possuem número de linhas diferentes, relativo as datas disponíveis de cada uma das séries.

Tentei utilizar a função `full_join` do pacote `dplyr`, mas só funcionou com 2 objetos por vez. O `cbind` não funciona pelos dados terem números de linha diferentes.

Exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame(data = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-07-01"), to = as.Date("2015-08-31"), 
                                length.out = as.Date("2015-08-31") - as.Date("2009-07-01")), x = c(1:2252))

y <- data.frame(data = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-07-01"), to = as.Date("2017-09-15"), 
                                length.out = as.Date("2017-09-15") - as.Date("2009-07-01")), y = c(1:2998))

z <- data.frame(data = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-07-01"), to = as.Date("2017-09-15"), 
                                length.out = as.Date("2010-09-15") - as.Date("2009-07-01")), z = c(1:441))

dados <- full_join(x, y, z)
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Erro: `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for natural joins (not recommended in production code), not a `data.frame` object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As funções `*_join`, do pacote `dplyr`, só estão definidas para operações com dois objetos de cada vez. Felizmente é possível aplicá-las em mais de um objeto simultaneamente utilizando a função `reduce` do pacote `purr`, que também faz parte do `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(data = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-07-01"), 
                                to = as.Date("2015-08-31"), 
                                length.out = as.Date("2015-08-31") - as.Date("2009-07-01")), 
                x = c(1:2252))

y <- data.frame(data = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-07-01"), 
                                to = as.Date("2017-09-15"),
                                length.out = as.Date("2017-09-15") - as.Date("2009-07-01")), 
                y = c(1:2998))

z <- data.frame(data = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-07-01"), 
                                to = as.Date("2017-09-15"), 
                                length.out = as.Date("2010-09-15") - as.Date("2009-07-01")), 
                z = c(1:441))

df_final <- list(x, y, z) %>% 
    reduce(full_join, by = "data")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Notei que na hora de juntar as datas, alguns dados possuem datas iguais, mas estão aparecendo com ```NA```.

Comment: Experimente converter as datas para *character* antes da união. A *Date* é uma exibição "arredondada" da POSIX, duas datas iguais podem corresponder à valores numéricos diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Para ficar registrado: o mesmo pode ser feito apenas com funções do *base*:

```
dados <- Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, all = TRUE), list(x, y, z))
```

- `merge` une dois *data frames* por uma coluna de identificação (por padrão, qualquer nome que for comum aos dois); a opção `all = TRUE` mantém todas as ids.
- `Reduce` aplica uma função à uma lista sequencialmente.